# Get Ace Editor object after page loading

Tags: javascript, ace-editor

I successfully initialize the Ace Editor elements in the code below.

```
                <script>
                    var editor = ace.edit('Editor_@index');

                    editor.setTheme("ace/theme/tomorrow");
                    editor.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/csharp");
                    editor.renderer.setShowGutter(false);
                    editor.setReadOnly(true);
                    editor.resize();
                    editor.setOptions({
                        maxLines: editor.session.getLength()
                    });
                </script>
```

But how can I get these items after the page loads? There is many editors on page, @index is variable.

Comment: why don't you just call that code after the page loads? then you can call `editor` where you need it.

Comment: I use this code for @foreach loop, where dynamically create html code from data, so variable editor overwritten on each iteration.

Comment: You can create different variables, or create array of editors, or add a js loop that will go over all 'Editor_@index' and create editors.